# Как сделать адаптивное приложение без медиа запросов по макету дизайнера?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animation, inkscape

Подскажите пожалуйста, как  лучше сверстать в данном случае, соты?
Я верстал подобное, но там были одинаковые бордеры (Приложил код).
В данном же случае, все куда труднее и у меня нет особо идей как это лучше сделать.
И второй вопрос, как грамотно спозиционировать эти блоки, чтобы потом не сильно костылить медиа запросами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.benefits__wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3.9881vw;
  padding-bottom: 15px; }

.benefits__heading {
  margin-bottom: 6.84524vw; }

.benefits__items {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 759px) {
    .benefits__items {
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 759px) {
  .benefits__item {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 20px 0; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 459px) {
  .benefits__item {
    width: 100%; } }

.item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 40px; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 459px) {
    .item {
      margin-right: 0; } }
  .item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0; }
  .item__title {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    font: 1.25rem/1 "PFEncoreSansPro-Regular";
    color: #868686;
    margin-bottom: 34px; }
  .item__info {
    font: 0.9375rem/1.125rem "PFEncoreSansPro-Thin";
    color: #adadad;
    margin-bottom: 3.03571vw; }

.hexagon {
  margin: 0 auto 54px; }
  .hexagon__icon {
    fill: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .35s;
    transition: background-color .35s; }

.hexagon,
.hexagon__item_inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 91px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #fe8682;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .35s;
  transition: background-color .35s; }

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fe8682;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .35s;
  transition: background-color .35s; }

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon__item_inner:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
          transform: rotate(120deg); }

.hexagon:after,
.hexagon__item_inner:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
          transform: rotate(60deg); }

.hexagon__item_inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
          transform: scale(0.9);
  background-color: #fc635e;
  z-index: 1; }

.hexagon__item_inner:before,
.hexagon__item_inner:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .35s;
  transition: background-color .35s;
  background-color: #fc635e; }

.hexagon__content {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1; }

.hexagon:hover,
.hexagon:hover:before,
.hexagon:hover:after {
  background-color: #fc635e; }

.hexagon:hover .hexagon__item_inner,
.hexagon:hover .hexagon__item_inner:before,
.hexagon:hover .hexagon__item_inner:after {
  background-color: #fff; }

.hexagon:hover .hexagon__icon {
  fill: #fc635e; }
```

```html
<section class="benefits">
      <div class="benefits__wrapper container">
        <div class="benefits__heading">
          <div class="heading_usual">
            <div class="heading__title uppercase">What can
              <div class="span heading_active">you receive?</div>
            </div>
            <div class="heading__subtitle">
              Daisy is sagittis sem nibh id elit.   Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a 
                sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="benefits__items">
          <article class="benefits__item item">
            <div class="hexagon">
              <div class="hexagon__item_inner"></div>
              <div class="hexagon__content">
                <svg class="hexagon__icon icon_xl">
                  <use xlink:href="svg/sprite.svg#rocket"></use>
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item__title uppercase">Clents</div>
            <div class="item__info">
              This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum.   Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean</div>
          </article>
          <article class="benefits__item item">
            <div class="hexagon">
              <div class="hexagon__item_inner"></div>
              <div class="hexagon__content">
                <svg class="hexagon__icon icon_xl">
                  <use xlink:href="svg/sprite.svg#web-design"></use>
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item__title uppercase">branding</div>
            <div class="item__info">
              This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum.   Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean</div>
          </article>
          <article class="benefits__item item">
            <div class="hexagon">
              <div class="hexagon__item_inner"></div>
              <div class="hexagon__content">
                <svg class="hexagon__icon icon_xl">
                  <use xlink:href="svg/sprite.svg#diagram"></use>
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item__title uppercase">marketing</div>
            <div class="item__info">
              This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum.   Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean</div>
          </article>
          <article class="benefits__item item">
            <div class="hexagon">
              <div class="hexagon__item_inner"></div>
              <div class="hexagon__content">
                <svg class="hexagon__icon icon_xl">
                  <use xlink:href="svg/sprite.svg#speaker"></use>
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item__title uppercase">adv.</div>
            <div class="item__info">
              This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum.   Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean</div>
          </article>
        </div>
```

Comment: Сохранить из Photohop как изображение и использовать или background или как img

Comment: Примерно так : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/RdNRXo  если не получится доделать ...напишите об этом

Comment: Огромное спасибо что откликнулись! Очень помогли, осталось разобраться только в теме)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### SVG решение

У SVG решения есть ряд преимуществ:

- Кроссбраузерность, -   работает во всех современных браузерах плюс `IE11`, `Edge`
- Полная адаптивность, - ваша вёрстка никогда не сломается при любом размере дисплея

**Пошаговая инструкция:**

- Для получения точной привязки контуров фигур к фоновой картинке
  загружаем картинку в векторный редактор и присваиваем значения  svg в
  соответствии с габаритными размерами картинки.

  `width="1330" height="880" viewBox="0 0 1330 880"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1330" height="880" viewBox="0 0 1330 880" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb744.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

- В векторном редакторе с помощью инструмента - `Рисовать кривые Безье
  и прямые отрезки`

  наносим узловые точки по контурам красной линии и шестиугольников

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл svg, забираем из него `path` общей
  линии и  шестиугольников.
- Добавляем в каждый шестиугольник текст, который  позиционируем
  координатами `X,`Y`

  `<text class="txt1" x="355" y="400"  > STEP
   <tspan dx="0">1 </tspan></text>`

  Добавляем картинку в шестиугольник с помощью `pattern`

`<pattern
       id="pattern"
       x="0px" y="-255px"
       width="341px"
       height="382px"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSbkL.jpg"
        width="341px"
       height="382px"
       />
    </pattern>`

- Добавляем красные кружки с галочкой, вместо них можно добавить иконки, как на
  эскизе

`<g id="crc1">
   <circle  r="23" fill="#FC635E"/>
    <text x="-15" y="15" fill="white" font-size="36" >&#10004;</text>
</g>`

**Ниже полный пример кода, добавил анимацию общей линии**

```css
 .h1{
 fill-opacity:0.6;
  } 
 
  .h2 {
 fill-opacity:0.9;
  }
 .txt1 {
  font-size:32px;
  fill:#595959;
  text-decoration: underline;
   font-weight:500;
   } 
  .txt2 {
  font-size:20px;
  fill:#444444;
   font-weight:500;
   } 
 tspan {
 fill:#FC635E;
 font-weight:500;
 font-size:36px;
  }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1330 880"  >  
<defs> 
  <pattern
       id="pattern"
       x="0px" y="-255px"
       width="341px"
    height="382px"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSbkL.jpg"
        width="341px"
    height="382px"
       />
    </pattern>  
 <pattern
       id="pattern2"
       x="40px" y="-380px"
         width="304px"
      height="343px"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZrmI.jpg"
             width="304px"
          height="343px"
       />
    </pattern>   
 <g id="crc1">
 <circle  r="23" fill="#FC635E" />   
    <text x="-15" y="15" fill="white" font-size="36" >&#10004;</text>
   </g>
</defs>

    
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC31J.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />    

 
  
 <g fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="gray" stroke-width="2">    
  <path id="hex_1" class="h1" d="m402.1 321 106.8 60.6v121.3l-106.8 64.6-106.8-64.6V381.7ZM731.7 381.7l104.1 60.6" />
  <path id="hex_2" class="h1" d="m731.7 381.7 104.1 60.6v125.2l-104.1 64.6-106.8-64.6V442.3Z" />
  <path id="hex_3" class="h2" fill-opacity="0.6" style="fill:url(#pattern2);" d="m1099.5 289.4 163.5 92.3V567.6L1099.5 658.5 940 567.6V381.7l159.5-92.3" /> 
  <path class="h2" fill-opacity="0.9"  style="fill:url(#pattern);" d="m508.9 503 160.8 94.9V782.4L508.9 876 349.4 782.4V597.9l159.5-94.9M835.8 199.7l104.1 62" class="s0"/>
  <path class="h1" d="m835.8 199.7 104.1 62v120l-104.1 60.6-104.1-60.6V261.7Z" class="s0"/>
</g>  

 <path id="progress" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="red"  stroke-dashoffset="1975"    stroke-dasharray="1975"
     d="m295.3 381.7 106.8-60.6 106.8 60.6v121.3l116 64.6 0-125.2 106.8-60.6V261.7l104.1-62 104.1  62v120l159.5-92.3 163.5 92.3v185.9l-163.5 91" >
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="10s" values="1975;0" fill="freeze"/> 
  </path>   
  
 <text class="txt1" x="355" y="400"  > STEP
     <tspan dx="0">1 </tspan></text>   
     <text class="txt2" x="312" y="450"> Разработка проекта</text>
    <text class="txt2" x="300" y="490"> Согласование проекта </text>
 
   <text class="txt1" x="425" y="725"  > STEP 
     <tspan dx="0">2 </tspan></text>  
      <text class="txt1" x="680" y="450"  > STEP 
       <tspan dx="0">3 </tspan></text>   
      <text class="txt2" x="670" y="500"> Нулевой цикл</text>
      <text class="txt2" x="640" y="540"> Возведение коробки </text>
    
    
   <text class="txt1" x="790" y="280"  > STEP 
       <tspan dx="0">4 </tspan></text>   
         <text class="txt2" x="750" y="330"> Монтажные работы</text>
      <text class="txt2" x="750" y="370"> Отделочные работы </text>
         
     <text class="txt1" x="1150" y="430"  > STEP 
       <tspan dx="0">5 </tspan></text>       
   <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="300" y="380" /> 
    <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="628" y="440" /> 
   <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="735" y="255" /> 
     <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="945" y="385" />
     <use xlink:href="#crc1" x="1100" y="655" />
  
</svg>
```

**CSS решение** этого учебного топика можно найти по ссылке, [которую указал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cibmycvhUs) @UModeL

Comment: Шикарное пошаговое пояснение! Спасибо!

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам! Все очень доходчиво и понятно!

Comment: Только не могу понять как мне добавить после STEP много текста, ведь тут текст не переносится сам.

Comment: @ГлебРостишевский Добавляйте другой текст с помощью команд `<tspan>`, как в примере ниже. Либо  с помощью `<text>` для каждой строки но координаты `X ` `Y` придётся менять.  Заметьте, если бы это была CSS вёрстка, вам тоже пришлось бы подбирать длину фраз и не было бы автопереноса, так как у вас не прямоугольная форма, а шестиугольник

Comment: Спасибо, попробую разобраться.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, повторюсь... Тебе в пору писать книгу по `svg`... )

Answer (score 7):

### Анимация процесса выполнения проекта

*Сценарий анимации*

1. Анимация красной линии происходит на протяжении  выполнения всего проекта
2. Последовательно появляется текст внутри каждого шестиугольника, раскрывая суть этапа
3. По мере завершения определенного этапа загорается красная иконка с чекбоксом.

Реализовать такой сценарий не трудно, так как все анимации будут следовать друг за другом и лишь одна анимация рисования общей линии длится в течение всей анимации.
Эта анимация реализована на изменении атрибута `stroke-dashoffset` от максимального значения длины  линии `1975px` до нуля.

Остальные анимации появления текста, иконок основаны на изменении прозрачности.

Ниже полный код. Анимация начинается после клика на кнопку - **Start**

```css
.h1 {
 fill-opacity:0.6;
 
 } 
 
  .h2 {
 fill-opacity:0.9;
 
 }
 .txt1 {
  font-size:32px;
  fill:#595959;
  text-decoration: underline;
   font-weight:500;
   fill-opacity:0.2;
   } 
  .txt2 {
  font-size:20px;
  fill:#444444;
   font-weight:500;
    fill-opacity:0.2;
   } 
 tspan {
 fill:#FC635E;
 font-weight:500;
 font-size:36px;
 fill-opacity:1;
  }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1330 880"  >  
<defs> 
  <pattern
       id="pattern"
       x="0px" y="-255px"
       width="341px"
    height="382px"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSbkL.jpg"
        width="341px"
    height="382px"
    
       />
    </pattern>  
 <pattern
       id="pattern2"
       x="40px" y="-380px"
         width="304px"
      height="343px"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image
         xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZrmI.jpg"
             width="304px"
          height="343px"
       />
    </pattern>  
   <g id="crc1" >
 <circle  r="23" fill="#FC635E" />   
    <text x="-15" y="15" fill="white" font-size="36" >&#10004;</text>
   </g>
 
</defs>
           <!-- Картинка фона -->
    
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC31J.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />    

    <!-- Блок шестиугольников --> 
  
 <g fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="gray" stroke-width="2">    
  <path id="hex_1" class="h1" d="m402.1 321 106.8 60.6v121.3l-106.8 64.6-106.8-64.6V381.7ZM731.7 381.7l104.1 60.6" />
  <path id="hex_2" class="h1" d="m731.7 381.7 104.1 60.6v125.2l-104.1 64.6-106.8-64.6V442.3Z" />
  <path id="hex_3" class="h2" fill-opacity="0.6" style="fill:url(#pattern2);" d="m1099.5 289.4 163.5 92.3V567.6L1099.5 658.5 940 567.6V381.7l159.5-92.3" /> 
  <path id="h2" class="h2" fill-opacity="0.9"  style="fill:url(#pattern);" d="m508.9 503 160.8 94.9V782.4L508.9 876 349.4 782.4V597.9l159.5-94.9M835.8 199.7l104.1 62" class="s0"/>
  <path class="h1" d="m835.8 199.7 104.1 62v120l-104.1 60.6-104.1-60.6V261.7Z" class="s0"/>
</g>  

 <path id="progress" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#FC635E"  stroke-dashoffset="1975"    stroke-dasharray="1975"
     d="m295.3 381.7 106.8-60.6 106.8 60.6v121.3l116 64.6 0-125.2 106.8-60.6V261.7l104.1-62 104.1  62v120l159.5-92.3 163.5 92.3v185.9l-163.5 91" >
      <animate id="an_Line" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="btn.click" dur="20s" values="1975;0" fill="freeze"/> 
  </path>     
  
 <text class="txt1" id="s1" x="355" y="400"  > STEP
     <tspan  dx="0">1 </tspan></text>   
     <text id="s11" class="txt2" x="312" y="450"> Разработка проекта</text>
    <text id="s111" class="txt2" x="300" y="490"> Согласование проекта </text>
 
   <text id="s2" class="txt1" x="425" y="725"  > STEP 
     <tspan dx="0">2 </tspan></text>  
      <text id="s3" class="txt1" x="680" y="450"  > STEP 
       <tspan dx="0">3 </tspan></text>   
      <text id="s33" class="txt2" x="670" y="500"> Нулевой цикл</text>
      <text id="s333" class="txt2" x="640" y="540"> Возведение коробки </text>
    
    
   <text id="s4" class="txt1" x="790" y="280"  > STEP 
       <tspan dx="0">4 </tspan></text>   
         <text id="s44" class="txt2" x="750" y="330"> Монтажные работы</text>
      <text id="s444" class="txt2" x="750" y="370"> Отделочные работы </text>
         
     <text id="s5" class="txt1" x="1150" y="430"  > STEP 
       <tspan dx="0">5 </tspan></text>       
   <!-- Блок красных иконок --> 
 <g fill-opacity="0.2">   
   <use id="u1" xlink:href="#crc1" x="300" y="380"  /> 
    <use  id="u3" xlink:href="#crc1" x="628" y="440" /> 
   <use id="u4" xlink:href="#crc1" x="735" y="255" /> 
     <use id="u5" xlink:href="#crc1" x="945" y="385" />
     <use id="u55" xlink:href="#crc1" x="1100" y="655" />   
 </g> 
  <!-- Анимация текста шестиугольника STEP1 --> 
 <animate id="an_s1" 
    xlink:href="#s1" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_Line.begin+1s" values="0.2;1"   fill="freeze" />
 <animate id="an_s11"
   xlink:href="#s11" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s1.end" values="0.2;1" fill="freeze" />
 <animate id="an_s111"  
     xlink:href="#s111" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s11.end" values="0.2;1" fill="freeze" />   
    <!-- Анимация иконки шестиугольника STEP1 --> 
  <animate id="an_u1"   xlink:href="#u1" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s111.end" values="0.2;1"   fill="freeze" /> 
   <!-- Анимация текста шестиугольника STEP2 --> 
  <animate id="an_s2"
    xlink:href="#s2" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s111.end" values="0.2;1" fill="freeze" />   
      <!-- Анимация текста шестиугольника STEP3 --> 
 <animate id="an_s3"
    xlink:href="#s3" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s2.end" values="0.2;1" fill="freeze" /> 
  <animate id="an_s33"
    xlink:href="#s33" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s3.end" values="0.2;1" fill="freeze" />   
 <animate id="an_s333"
    xlink:href="#s333" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s33.end" values="0.2;1" fill="freeze" /> 
 <!-- Анимация иконки  STEP3 --> 
  <animate id="an_u3"   xlink:href="#u3" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s333.end" values="0.2;1"   fill="freeze" /> 

 <!-- Анимация текста шестиугольника STEP4 --> 
 <animate id="an_s4"
    xlink:href="#s4" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s333.end" values="0.2;1" fill="freeze" />
<animate id="an_s44"
    xlink:href="#s44" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s4.end" values="0.2;1" fill="freeze" /> 
<animate id="an_s444"
    xlink:href="#s444" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s44.end" values="0.2;1" fill="freeze" />
<!-- Анимация иконки  STEP4 --> 
 <animate id="an_u4" 
     xlink:href="#u4" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s444.end" values="0.2;1"    fill="freeze" />  
<animate id="an_u5" 
     xlink:href="#u5" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_u4.end+1s" values="0.2;1"    fill="freeze" />    

 <!-- Анимация текста шестиугольника STEP5 -->
<animate id="an_s5"
    xlink:href="#s5" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_s444.end+5s" values="0.2;1" fill="freeze" />
   <!-- Анимация второй иконки после завершения рисования линии  STEP5 -->
<animate id="an_u55" 
     xlink:href="#u55" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_Line.end" values="0.2;1"    fill="freeze" /> 
  
  <g id="btn" transform="translate(0 -100) scale(2)">
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="35" height="15" rx="5" fill="none" stroke="purple"/>
      <text x="28" y="95" font-size="10" fill="purple" >Start</text>
    </g>   
</svg>
```